# How to tell if the client side makes a socket?

Tags: javascript, sockets, websocket, socket.io

I'm making a program using the socket.io library.

I just have some basic code for the socket to work, but I'm concerned that somebody can just make a socket through the front end.

For example, my current frontend javascript is as follows:

```
// connection
const socket = io.connect("http://localhost:1234");
```

What's to stop anybody from just taking that line and spamming it into the console a bunch of times to make more sockets? How can I tell if these are fake?

Comment: I don't think you can, really. You could add authorization, maybe, but the user could still figure out how it gets configured and type it themselves into the console.

Comment: Do you offer registration functionality for your program? If not, it's open to the world.

Comment: What stops someone from opening a bunch of tabs of your program?